# Setting a dynamic value for a session variable

Tags: magento-1, core-session, giftmessage

Can any one help me why am not able to set a magento session variable with the following code.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setGiftMessage("<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery('#gift_message').val();</script>");
```

If the above implementation is wrong then please tell me how can i get a value of a text area

```
<textarea id="gift_message" rows="2" cols="75" name="gift-message"></textarea>
```

and set that value in a magento session variable to use it later.

Many thanks in advance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the value is sent through post as some controller.
Just add this in the controller that handles the request:

```
$var = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('gift_message'); //$_POST['gift_message']
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setGiftMessage($var);
```

Later you should be able to get it like this:

```
$val = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getGiftMessage()
```

or if you want to retrieve it and remove it from session use this

```
$val = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getGiftMessage(true)
```

Comment: great explain: or if you want to retrieve it and remove it from session use this `$val = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getGiftMessage(true)` it is also for magento2